# REST API POST call failing with JPASystemException

Tags: hibernate, rest, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to insert some data into Snowflake database with POST method API but it is failing with some below error:

`2023-06-06T08:07:33.581+05:30 DEBUG 78468 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL : insert into SOME_DATA (a_status, c_name, sector) values (?, ?, ?) 2023-06-06T08:07:33.584+05:30  WARN 78468 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper    : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null 2023-06-06T08:07:33.585+05:30 ERROR 78468 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper    : null 2023-06-06T08:07:34.299+05:30 ERROR 78468 --- [nio-8081-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]     : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request       processing failed: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement] with root  cause net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException: null`

However, GET API is able to fetch the data from Snowflake DB & table. Can anyone please help how this could be fixed?

I tried changing the Snowflake JDBC and Hibernate versions but no luck.

Currently used configurations:

`spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver`
`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.1.0'`
`implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.3.29.Final'`
`implementation 'net.snowflake:snowflake-common:5.1.4'`
`implementation 'net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.13.30'`
`implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33'`

Comment: The error suggests you are trying to use a method that's not implemented by Snowflake JDBC as you're getting `SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException`. Can you post a snippet of code that you are trying to implement?

Comment: you tagged this with `spring-data-jdbc` but you seem to be using JPA, possibly `spring-data-jpa`, could you please clarify?